# Can we rearrange a matrix of ones in matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Take $(X'X)^{-1}X'CX(X'X)^{-1}$ where X is an nxn matrix and C is an nxn matrix of ones.

If I could rearrange C somehow then I could use the fact that $(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1} = (X'X)^{-1} $ to get an easy simplification. Is some sort of rearrangement possible?

Comment: The most obvious thing to use is that $C=uu’$ where $u$ is a column vectors of ones.

Comment: can you then write $(X'X)^{-1}X'CX(X'X)^{-1}$ = $u(X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1}u'$?

Comment: Absolutely not. The former product is an n-by-n matrix and the latter is a scalar.

Comment: How does C=uu′ lead to any simplifications?

Comment: should it be $uu'[X^TX]^{-1}$

Comment: I'm not sure this is a "simplification" in the sense that you're interested in, but if we take $v = (X'X)^{-1}X'u$, then your product can be written as $M = vv'$.